# Downloading images with BeautifulSoup when complete image link does not appear unless hovering over the src tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download images from [this](http://ottofrello.dk/malerierstor.htm) page. I wrote the following Python script:

```
import requests
import subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("http://ottofrello.dk/malerierstor.htm")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = soup.find_all("img")
for img in element:
    print (img.get('src'))
```

However, I get only the image names and not the complete path. On the site, I can hover over the image name when I inspect the html and the link appears. Is there any way I can parse this link using BeautifulSoup?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAUNy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image URIs in your page are marked up relative to the hostname.

You can build an absolute url for each image using `urljoin` function in `urllib.parse` module.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

page_url = "http://ottofrello.dk/malerierstor.htm"
request = requests.get(page_url)


...
    for img in element:
        image_url = urljoin(
            page_url, 
            img.get('src')
        )
        print(image_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are interested in absolute image path and not the relative path which you are getting right now. The only change I made is in your print statement.

```
import requests
import subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("http://ottofrello.dk/malerierstor.htm")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = soup.find_all("img")
for img in element:
    print ('http://ottofrello.dk/' + img.get('src'))
```